# Flex, Bison, C++ - compile error

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'd like to make a program, that creates parse tree for functions.
For instance: "f(g(x,h(y),v,k(l(c))))" could be a valid function call.

h1.l

```
%{
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
#include "h1.tab.hpp"

%}

%option noyywrap
%option c++

%%

[a-z][a-zA-z0-9]*       { yylval.s = yytext; return (TERM_ID); }
"("                     { return (OP); }
")"                     { return (CP); }
";"                     { return (COMMA); }

%%
```

h1.ypp

```
%{

#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


extern "C" int yylex(); 
extern "C" int yyerror(char *p) { cerr << "Error!" << endl; }

struct ts {
    string                  *name;
    list<struct ts*>        *plist; /* NULL if the sturcture represents a variable, parameter list if the structure represents a function */
};

%}

%union {
    struct ts *t;
    list<struct ts *> *tl;
    char *s;
}

%token <s> TERM_ID
%token OP CP COMMA

%type <tl> termlist
%type <t> term


%%

term : TERM_ID OP termlist CP   { $$ = new struct ts(); $$->name = new string($1); $$->plist = $3; }
    | TERM_ID   { $$ = new struct ts(); $$->name = new string($1); $$->plist = NULL; }
;

termlist : termlist COMMA term  { $$ = $1; $$->push_back($3); }
    | term  { $$ = new list<struct ts*>(); $$->push_back($1); }
;


%%

int main()
{
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling:

```
$ bison -d h1.ypp
$ flex h1.l 
$ g++ h1.tab.cpp lex.yy.cc
h1.tab.cpp: In function ‘int yyparse()’:
h1.tab.cpp:1382: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
h1.tab.cpp:1528: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_yylex", referenced from:
      yyparse()    in ccmRHVKn.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I dont know much about these tools, also I have never used cpp before.

What should I change to make these things work?

Comment: The issue is with the Linker. It is not able to find the definition of `yylex` function ? Are you compiling the source file in which it's definition is present ?

Comment: The flex tool generates the yylex() function.  You must not be compiling the source code it generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're generating a C++ lexer class (using `%option c++` in the .l file), while bison is expecting a C `yylex` function.  Remove the `%option c++` and instead add `extern "C" int yyex();` to the top of the `.l` file (or remove the `extern "C"` from the `.y` file) and all should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're generating a C++ `yylex` and then declaring it as `extern "C"` in your parser. A C++ function and a C function do not have the same name (even though they appear to) and consequently the linker can't find `yylex` (or `_yylex`, as it is actually called.)

Remove the extern "C" from both declarations and it will probably link.

You should change `char* s` in your `%union` to `std::string* s`; otherwise, you'll run into one of the most common bison/flex problems for beginners: the C-string `yytext` points to is only valid until `yylex` is called the next time, so that when bison gets around to using the pointer, it's pointing to a different string.

So you need to make a copy of `yytext` in the lexer, not in the parser. Consequently, in your lexer, you would do:

```
yylval.s = new std::string(yytext);
```

and in your grammar, you would do (for example):

```
term : TERM_ID OP termlist CP   { 
         $$ = new struct ts();
         $$->name = $1;        // <-- Here is the change
         $$->plist = $3;
       }
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error messages:
h1.ypp:23: error: member ‘std::string YYSTYPE::s’ with constructor not allowed in union
h1.ypp:23: error: member ‘std::string YYSTYPE::s’ with destructor not allowed in union
h1.ypp:23: error: member ‘std::string YYSTYPE::s’ with copy assignment operator not allowed in union

Comment: @DavidAngyal: Oops. That's true, you can't put strings in unions; it would have to be a struct. You'll have to make it a string* and change the assignment to `yylval.s = new std::string(yytext)`; then in your bison actions where you have a `TERM_ID`, instead of $$->name = `new string($1)`, you can just do `$$->name = $1`. (changed answer to reflect comment)

Comment: Now, this message again: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "yylex()", referenced from:
      yyparse()    in ccXWYT6Z.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Renamed from ".ypp" to ".y", and removed the "%option c++" from the flex file, and now its working!